# Make two dimensional array

Tags: ruby

My array is `["Mehmet,1,3,0,0,0\n", "Veli,2,1,2,0,2\n", "Ali,0,1,1,0,0\n"]`.

I want to **declare two dimensional array** like `array[1][2]` with first dimension for name and second one for note.

How can I make it?

Text.txt is

Mehmet,1,3,0,0,0
Veli,2,1,2,0,2
Ali,0,1,1,0,0

My code is

```
filename = "text.txt"
results = []
File.new(filename, "r").each { |line| results << line }

results.inject([]){|ar,s|
ar.concat(s.split(/,/))}


puts results.inspect
```

Comment: You should start with formulating your question better. Post an expected result, for example.

Comment: Can you explain ? I don't understand because I am new on ruby.

Comment: Do you want to declare 2D array in code or do you want to transform your initial array into 2D array form?

Comment: Declara 2D array or initial array into 2D array form . Whatever you want. I can use Both of them

Comment: If you would like to declare 2D array, you can use my suggestion in below entry :)

Comment: You can also referance this web site for more information on arrays: http://progzoo.net/wiki/Ruby:Creating_an_Array

Answer (score 1):

```
array = File.read("text.txt").split
# => ["Mehmet,1,3,0,0,0", "Veli,2,1,2,0,2", "Ali,0,1,1,0,0"]

array.map { |ar| x, *xs = ar.split(","); [x, xs.join] }
# => [["Mehmet", "13000"], ["Veli", "21202"], ["Ali", "01100"]]
```

Or, if you don't want to join the second sub-array

```
array.map { |ar| x, *xs = ar.split(","); [x, xs] }
# => [["Mehmet", ["1", "3", "0", "0", "0"]],
#     ["Veli", ["2", "1", "2", "0", "2"]],
#     ["Ali", ["0", "1", "1", "0", "0"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the set that you first posted:

```
data = ["Mehmet,1,3,0,0,0\n", "Veli,2,1,2,0,2\n", "Ali,0,1,1,0,0\n"]
data = data.map {|x| y = x.split(","); [y.delete_at(0), y] }

=> [["Mehmet", ["1", "3", "0", "0", "0\n"]],
 ["Veli", ["2", "1", "2", "0", "2\n"]],
 ["Ali", ["0", "1", "1", "0", "0\n"]]]

puts data[0][0] 
=> Mehmet
```

Answer (score 0):

2d array means array of arrays. So, simply it can be like:

```
board = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],[ 4, 5, 6 ]]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. But i think question is not clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
array = ["Mehmet,1,3,0,0,0\n", "Veli,2,1,2,0,2\n", "Ali,0,1,1,0,0\n"]
new_array = array.map do |elem|
  splited = elem.split(/[,\s]/)
  [splited.shift, splited]
end
# => [["Mehmet", ["1", "3", "0", "0", "0"]],
#     ["Veli", ["2", "1", "2", "0", "2"]],
#     ["Ali", ["0", "1", "1", "0", "0"]]]
```